# Creating multiple child process in C using fork

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I am creating a program to check the number of best and worst hands created when a card in hand is replaced with another card. I am asked to do it by creating multiple processes using fork(). Here is what I have done so far:

```
for(i = 1; i <= replacement; i++) {
        replaceCard = (char *)malloc(3);
        strcpy(replaceCard, argv[5+i]);
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Fork Failed! \n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Child %d, pid %d: replacing %s\n", i, getpid(), replaceCard);
            worse = 0; best = 0;
            for(j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
                for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    if (strcmp(hand[k], replaceCard) == 0)
                        strcpy(handCopy[k], deck[j]);
                    else
                        strcpy(handCopy[k], hand[k]);
                }
                if(isStraightFlush(handCopy))
                    newRank = 9;
                else if(isFourKind(handCopy))
                    newRank = 8;
                else if(isFullHouse(handCopy))
                    newRank = 7;
                else if(isFlush(handCopy))
                    newRank = 6;
                else if(isStraight(handCopy))
                    newRank = 5;
                else if(isThreePair(handCopy))
                    newRank = 4;
                else if(isTwoPair(handCopy))
                    newRank = 3;
                else if(isOnePair(handCopy))
                    newRank = 2;
                else
                    newRank = 1;

                if(newRank > currRank)
                    ++best;
                else if(newRank < currRank)
                    ++worse;
            }
            
            printf("Child %d, pid %d: %d best hands and %d worse hands\n", i, getpid(), best, worse);
            if(best > worse)
                exit(i);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            printf("Parent, PID %d: hand is < ", getpid());
            for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                printf("%s ", hand[i]);
            }
            printf(">\n");
            
            wait(&status);
            printf("Parent, pid %d: ", getpid());
            if(WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)
                printf("Child %d suggests to replace %s\n", i, replaceCard);
            
        }
        free(replaceCard);
    }
```

This is the segment of the code I am facing issues. My code is working fine if only one child process is required, but it is creating **only one child** when multiple children are required.

*This code is for an assignment, I can understand if nobody wants to comment on it, but I do not want a solution. I am new to C and OS concepts and I am just wondering what is the issue here. A little diagnosis with the error will help me. Also, I know the code is not clean.*

Comment: What is the value of `replacement`? Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, how are you determining that only one child is created? Your code has a `wait` call that waits for each child to exit before creating the next child - is that really what you want as generally the point of having multiple processes is so that they can all run concurrently.

Comment: This is basically a question about starting multiple child processes. It would be helpful to strip your code of anything not relevant to starting new processes (the hand/card stuff) and work with the bare minimum, not just for this post, but for easier debugging on your part.

Comment: `replacement = argc - 6` The input format is `./card ST HT DA CK HQ HT CK HQ` where the first 5 are the cards in hand and the next 3 are the cards to be replaced. If I do not use `wait`, isn't there a possibility of creating zombie processes? @kaylum

Comment: I'll implement your advice @wxz . Thank You!

Comment: I didn't mean don't use `wait.` Call `wait` in a loop **after** creating **all** the child processes.

Comment: That Worked @kaylum ! Thank you. Although now each of my processes are calculating 4 as best hands and 0 as worse hands. But I think I can manage that. THank you again!